# Incorrect work of Angular and Bootstrap: columns stretched only by the size of the content

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

```
    <div class="row">
        <div *ngFor="let column of columns">
            <div class="col">
                <div *ngFor="let cell of column">
                    ...cellcontent...
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here columns is a matrix (object[ ][ ]). I expect the columns to be the same and span the full width of the row, which is how bootstrap usually works.

[image]

That is, the columns are stretched only by the size of the content and do not occupy the entire row. Why does it work this way and how to achieve the correct behavior?

I definitely do not use styles that can break something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.col` has to be a direct `.row` child to work fine.

The problem is that you are wrapping your `.col` divs with another div (with no `.row` class)

*From your snippet*

```
 <div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let column of columns"> // This is the real column, but has no .col
        <div class="col">
            <div *ngFor="let cell of column">
                ...cellcontent...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Try updating your code as follow:

```
<div class="row">
    <div *ngFor="let column of columns" class="col"> // *ngFor and .col class in the same div
        <div *ngFor="let cell of column">
            ...cellcontent...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Since you were putting your `.col` inside a non-flex div (the one with ne `*ngFor`), the `.col` style was ignored.

---

If you want to keep your `*ngFor` separated for any reason, you could do the following using `ng-container` instead of `div` (since is not actually rendered in the browser), to iterate your columns.

*Like the following*

```
<div class="row">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let column of columns"> // This will render only the children
        <div class="col">
            <div *ngFor="let cell of column">
                ...cellcontent...
            </div>
        </div>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. (although now it’s not very clear why many columns are generated at all, and not just one, it seemed to me that only what is inside the ngfor div is copied, not this div itself)

Comment: `*ngFor` repeat the element to which it belongs for each item in the list (not only the children) :)  Take a look to the [angular *ngFor docs](https://angular.io/guide/built-in-directives#listing-items-with-ngfor) for more info.   If you look at the end of my anwer, you can see a solution to render only the children using `*ngFor`, but it's because of the `<ng-container>` behavior